# How could virtual properties in model classes violate the persistence ignorance principle?

Tags: c#, architecture, principles

I've just read (revised) some architectural principles (as documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/architectural-principles) and felt a bit confused about the `persistence ignorance` principle having a violation example like this:

```
 Properties requiring virtual keyword
```

So I don't get it clearly why such a requirement could violate the persistence ignorance principle. Provided that our model classes are just in C#, compiled by .NET compiler. To load a model instance, just create the class instance normally (with all properties initialized from the corresponding persistent data, e.g: a data record). To save it just read the values from the model instance and put it back to persistent storage (of any kind).

Actually `Entity Framework` does have that requirement to enable some cool features such as lazy loading, … And I do see that EF has been doing its great job to support various kinds of persistent storage (databases), which as I understand should be contrary to the so-called `a violation of the persistence ignorance principle`.

Could you give me some real-world example to demonstrate that `requiring virtual properties` could violate the persistence ignorance principle? If any present, isn't that sometimes we could not just comply with all the principles and we may have to take some trade-offs to balance between following good principles and having nice features (as in case of EF ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it violates the persistence ignorance principle is very simple: you have to make the properties `virtual` to make EF happy, so you changed the business code duo to a persistence concern. And besides directly violating the principle, using features of EF that override members of your class change the type of the class, so, for example, in your `Equals` implementation, you cannot use `GetType()` anymore to compare the two instances, as the actual type of the object is generated by EF at runtime, so again, you start to change your domain logic according to persistence concerns. On a side note, I would also advise against using EF's lazy loading in most cases, because it only works synchronously, blocking the current thread.

Comment: what do you mean by `you changed the business code duo to a persistence concern`? actually I see that `virtual` does not affect anything related to persistent store here, but I don't see any clue explaining against that in your answer. `lazy loading` is just one of features enabled by `virtual`. It's required by many frameworks not just by `Entity Framework` to intercept the property access and perform custom logic. The logic lies in the C# class (in the frameworks) and should not affect the data (which is persistent).

Comment: @Hopeless the change itself has nothing to do with persistence. The *reason* you performed the change to your business code is a requirement of EF (which is the "persistence" side of the application). The idea behind the principal is that when writing business code, you shouldn't be thinking about persistence at all. The `virtual` keyword changes the behavior of you business code: you can now override the properties in derived classes, which is fine if that's what you wanted, but if it doesn't come from a business intention it shouldn't affect the business code, according to the principal.

Comment: so you meant that `persistence` here is what of the code behavior/logic and not of data storage (as in `persistent store`)? Well I do think that's not what meant by the principle which states clearly that `just ignore the persistence`. If understanding it your way, we should turn `persistence ignorance` into something like `persistence cognizance`.

Comment: @Hopeless I'm not sure what you meant. Of course `persistence` refers to an entity store. But I think you confused `database-agnostic` code with `persistance ignorant` code. EF is DB-agnostic, but it's still a persistence mechanism. The `persistance ignorance principal` states that classes modeling domain concepts should not be *impacted* by the way they might be persisted. When writing domain code, you should be able to "forget" about EF completely, because it has nothing to do with the business logic of your system.

Comment: so `persistence` here means about the framework layer that uses the model classes to store the data, as EF, NHibernate, Dapper, ADO.NET … do? Actually there is one line in the original document confusing me here `Persistence choices might change over time, from one database technology to another`. It talks about `database technology` which makes me think about the things like SQL Server, Oracle, … If so I would say that it requires some effort to switch from this persistence framework to another one (such as from EF to NHibernate and vice-versa) ...

Comment: ...because of specific requirements to designing model classes in each persistence framework. But one more question, what do you think about the violation of EF, NHibernate … to that persistence ignorance principle here? is it worth it? Why do we have to violate a good architectural principle?

Comment: @Hopeless database technology is given there as an example to a "persistence choice", it's unlikely that you will store entities in something other than a database but in theory you could use BLOB storage or simple text files and your business code should not care. Moreover, the reason you want to decouple your code from EF core is not just to be able to switch to NHibetnate, but also to be able to easily move to a new fancy technology 10 years from now.

Comment: @Hopeless As to wether or not following that principal is worth it, it depends on the size of your project. Good  architecture usually pays off in the long run, but is more expensive initially. But still, if you only make your properties `virtual` or add protected parmeterless constructors, without referencing EF namespaces, you should be fine.

Comment: I'm sure that the `from one database technology to another [database technology]` all means about just `database technologies` (not involving other kinds of storage mechanism). So that is really confusing and should've not been written like so. Thanks for your explanation.